# Java preparestatement request doesn't work

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have a java code, where i'm doing a SQL request by using prepareStatement

```
String requete = "select * from VOreservation"
                + " where id_enseignant = ? and date_reservation = ? and id_creneau = ? ";

        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(requete);

        pstmt.setInt(1, ens.getIdEnseignant());
        pstmt.setDate(2, date);
        pstmt.setInt(3, creneau.getIdCreneau());

        ResultSet rset = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

I have a java.sql.sqlException, so It should be a problem with my request, but for me it is fine
The first and last parameters are number in my DB, and the second is a date (and date is here a java.sql.date)
I'm using the driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

my error is:

```
Fail to construct descriptor: Unable to resolve type: (my nested table type)
```

Comment: Why don't you tell us what the message and the stacktrace of the SQLException is? It namely contains the answer...

Comment: error in Reservation DB find: java.sql.SQLException: Echec de construction du descripteur: Unable to resolve type "USER.NTCARACT"

In fact I think it's a problem with nested tables in my View

Comment: The stacktrace is more than just a line. You should give all the stacktrace you have got.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be with the JDBC driver for the DBMS you are using. Not all drivers implement the standard completely and correctly. There is not enough information in your question to tell what goes wrong.

Comment: my error is: Fail to construct descriptor: Unable to resolve type: (my nested table type)